# Mouse events from inactive Windows on OSX in Qt

Tags: macos, qt

I've written a simple program in Qt that displays an undecorated window. I want the window to react to mouse events (Mouse Move) even if this window is not active. Right now the only chance is to click on the window, to make it active.
I know there exists the concept of NSTrackingArea on OSX. Can anybody give me a hint on how to implement this on Qt?
I'm working with Qt 4.8.3 right now.

Many thanks in advance.
Greetings, -chris-

Answer (score 0):

Inherit from QWindow and override

```
bool QWindow::event(QEvent * ev)
```

Comment: Sadly this is not working. If the window isn't active, there's no events sent to it.
I called installEventFilter(this); from my QWidgets constructor without receiving any events if the window is not active.

Comment: As you're finding out, by default, a window that is inactive is supposed to not handle the click event, other than to give the application focus. Therefore, I suggest to handle the event of getting focus and then grab the coordinates of the mouse until another mouse event occurs. I know it's not elegant, but should work. If I think of a better way, I'll let you know.